# Import psycopg2 from python script

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am trying to use psycopg2 installed by easy_install in a python script.

This is the header of my script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import sys,xml.sax
import psycopg2
```

When I execute it, an error happens :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./myscript.py", line 4, in <module>
      import psycopg2
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

But if I try in a basic python shell, it works well :

```
$ python2
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Oct  6 2010, 12:29:13)
[GCC 4.5.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
>>>
```

Do you have an explanation to this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Each sequence is being performed with a different installation of Python. Use `which python2` to verify.

Comment: It seems to use the same python installation : 
`$ which python2  
/usr/bin/python2`

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different Python interpreters. Triple check that.

Comment: I think I am using same python interpreter in two case : 

$ which python2
 /usr/bin/python2

Answer (score 0):

install python_select.this lets switch between different python versions.

```
sudo port install python_select
```

on the shell do

```
 python_select -l
```

try switching to the default python version.

for linux,  use virtualenv

```
 sudo pip install virtualenv      #install virual env

      mkdir ~/.virtualenvs      #make virtual envs directory

      export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs    #add environment variables
      source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
      source ~/.bashrc

     mkvirtualenv  foo  #make your virtual environment named foo
```

re install pysycopg2